I'm getting an error on the line .foregroundColor(Color.topcartcolor) in the code I provided above
import SwiftUI

extension Color{
    
    static let backgroundright =     LinearGradient(
        gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color(red: 55/255, green: 182/255, blue: 233/255),
                                    Color(red: 75/255, green: 76/255, blue: 237/255)]),
        startPoint: .top,
        endPoint: .bottom
    )
    
    static let primaryColor = Color("color1") // Sabit tanımlama
    static let secondaryColor = Color("color2")
    
    static let topcartcolor =   LinearGradient(
        gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color("topcart1"), Color("topcart2")]),
        startPoint: .leading,
        endPoint: .trailing
    )

    
}

This is my color file, and I want to use the topcartcolor here where I'm going to show below, but I'm getting an error.
import SwiftUI
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Arka plan simgesi
            firsticon()
                .fill(Color.backgroundright)
                .frame(width: 413, height: 720) // Genişlik ve yükseklik ayarlarını kontrol edin

            VStack {
                // İçeriği yukarı itmek için boşluk
                ZStack {
                    TopCart()
                        .frame(width: 350, height: 300)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.topcartcolor)
                        .padding(.top, 50)
                }
                Spacer()
                
                // TabBar bileşenini en alta yerleştiriyoruza
                ZStack {
                    TabBar()
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity) // Tam ekran kapsaması için
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .background(Color.primaryColor) // Arka plan rengi
    }
}


#Preview {
    ContentView()
}

I'm getting an error on the line .foregroundColor(Color.topcartcolor) in the code I provided above.

It might help if you provided the error (as text) IN the question

Edit your question to include the exact error message you are getting. Then we can reopen it and help you solve the issue.

Color.topcartcolor is not a Color, it is a LinearGradient, that is the reason why you get the error when you try to use it as a Color, like in your .foregroundColor(Color.topcartcolor) which takes a Color parameter. Just because you declare topcartcolor in extension Color does not make it a Color type.
To achieve what you want, try using:
.foregroundStyle(Color.topcartcolor)

which can take a LinearGradient as parameter.
